# Is 400+ MHz on a PCB practical?

Tags: rf

I have been working on an oscillator design and have been struggling with getting it work at 400+ MHz first on the breadboard but now on the PCB. I tried it on a perfboard, a breadboard, a copperboard and after careful experimentation, I was able to get an oscillation frequency of 12 MHz on the breadboard once. I tuned the L and C for 12 MHz and not for 400 MHz - I didn't find any breadboard nH inductors for that and wire winding them on an iron core didn't work. It seems very inconsistent. Sometimes it seems to work and then sometimes it doesn't. It is very frustrating. At any rate, I decided to try making a PCB version of the Colpitts oscillator with HFA3096 transistor. I soldered the smd components with a stencil and solder paste. The components are very tiny. In the end, it didn't work.
Is it possible to design this on a PCB?

[image]

[image]

components are 0402 inductors/capacitors and 0603 resistors.

Comment: This task is certainly impossible on a breadboard, but should be no problem on a PCB. Could you please post a picture of your PCB and the list of components you are using? And your schematics?

Comment: Simple enough, if you know what you're doing and lay out the board appropriately. At high frequencies it's pretty easy to make a mess of things with a poor PCB layout.

Comment: Forget breadboard. Ground plane perf board should be usable. With a manufactured PCB you can get to many GHz. For prototyping, use a solid ground plane, and 'dead bug' your components together.

Comment: @Ale..chenski It's not at all impossible. Very far from it. It just won't be practical, or particularly stable, or anything. See for example: https://www.eevblog.com/forum/projects/challenge-thread-the-fastest-breadboard-oscillator-on-the-mudball/

Comment: @TimWilliams , did you notice that the examples barely reach 10MHz? It is quite a far fetch from the requested 400MHz. (I didn't have time to parse all 15 pages of the blog, please correct me if I am wrong). Not many people realize that even a straight piece of wire of 1cm long already has its inductance of about 7nH, and every pin has capacitance of few pF. That's why I said 400MHz on breadboard is impossible.

Answer (score 9):

> Is 400+ MHz on a PCB practical?

Yes. Even the cheapest 2.4 GHz devices are on a PCB (bluetooth, wifi…), and 433 MHz radio devices on PCBs have been around since the early 1980s!

But your question is actually about building an *oscillator from discrete parts* on a PCB. That is a bit of a different problem! You can very well form waveguides on a PCB, and affect the RF signals transported on these with both discrete components and the shape of traces, stubs and shorts, but building an oscillator means you want to use an active component with gain together with some capacitive and/or inductive component to set the frequency. That works well on a PCB, still, but you will have to start looking into how even a short piece of trace on a PCB has its own inductance and capacitance; you can't just connect two components and act as if the connection is perfect anymore.

That makes the design of something finely tuned as a Colpitts oscillator a fair bit harder at 400 MHz than at 12 MHz. It's impossible to give you numbers without having enough information on the board material, thickness, and trace width and geometry so that one can effectively simulate the effect, but as an order of magnitude, a single cm of trace on 1.6 mm thick FR4 will have around 1 pF of capacitance to ground, and maybe 0.5 nH (these numbers are really just "rough order of magnitude to understand the level of uncertainty". Don't use them to calculate anything and expect that to be within a factor of 10 of the right result!). These values are low, easily two or three orders of magnitude lower than on a solderless breadboard, which is why things look better on a PCB than on such a breadboard. But they're still significant compared to the actual capacitor and inductor values you would want to use for an oscillator.

Now, when you model your Colpitts oscilator, you think about how the discrete inductors and capacitors shift the phase of the feedback from the output to the input of the amplifying transistor, depending on the frequency; after all, this difference plus the 180° degree inversion from the transistor needs to become a multiple of 360° for a sustained oscillation. That's the theory behind any oscillator.

Now, sadly, your textbook Colpitt assumes the transistor to be of high gain and for all practical matters fast enough to just count as 180° inverter. Sadly, that doesn't work in the RF domain: the transistor shifts the phase of the signal at its base relative to the collector. And aside from the frequency-dependent shift you can read from the S-parameter table in your HF transistor's [datasheet](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/dst/hfa3046-hfa3096-hfa3127-hfa3128-datasheet?r=494216), you also have to incorporate the the phase shift from the parasitic effects.

[image: Fig. 26.41: Equivalent circuit of an integrated oscillator]
<sup>Equivalent circuit of an integrated oscillator with external inductor. In this example, the active part of the Colpitts oscillator (probably more than just one transistor!) is connected to the right; this is the effective feedback network. You select the external inductor (leftmost box) to have, 100 nH, but you then incur a ohmic series resistance of 0.8Ω, and an inter-winding capacity of 0.2 pF. Then, transporting it into the package ("Gehäuse") of the integrated oscillator incurs another 3 nH parasitic line inductance, and a capacity to ground of 0.5 pF. Following are parasitic properties of the bond wire ("Bonddraht") and the bond pad, and finally the intended on-die capacitors. You have all the same effects in your transistor package, which is part of why your S-parameters don't look flat!</sup>
<sup>Image from: U. Tietze, C. Schenk, and E. Gamm, Halbleiter-Schaltungstechnik, 16th ed. Springer Vieweg, 2019.</sup>

So, I'm very sympathetic to you being frustrated – I can see how this isn't easy. There's good reason why *usually* oscillators above a couple dozen MHz are done in chips, not as discrete components on boards, and that is that you can put the transistor, and the analog components defining the oscillation frequency, within a few micrometers of each other, can control all parasitics to a degree that you use them as part of the working principle, and you tend to go for different architectures (if technically possible) than Colpitts. You picked a hard problem that most engineers solve by *not* solving it, but buying a chip that does all the things that are hard in discrete components internally. Not out of laziness, but out of necessity that things work reliably. (Also, and I've been hesitant to call that out so far, by design a Colpitts oscillator forms a current loop; 400 MHz and a current loop with significant current and cross-section, that's a loop antenna, and you might get into RFI trouble.)

So, how does one salvage your situation? Usually, you'd go and re-consider your choice of oscillator architecture (I'd tend towards a quartz Pierce oscillator with a square wave output and filtering to select the harmonic I want, instead, but honestly, I'd just buy a VCO+PLL combination chip…). If you decide to stick with a Colpitts oscillator, you'd want to first experiment at which frequency your oscillator oscillator by itself, changing component values until you get somewhat close to where you want to be, then would try putting a varactor diode in parallel with its inductor and thus tuning the resonant frequency. That seems to be a common technique in integrated VCOs. There's sadly no guarantee of success here, either: you really just picked a hard problem :)

Comment: what VCO/PLL chips combination would you suggest? I am not sure how I would choose a VCO +PLL or what considerations i should take into account other than voltage required to operate (should be 3V or less) and frequency.